# Undefined Symbols for Architecture x86_64: Building a Stack

Tags: c++, stack

I am using Xcode and receiving the following error messages when I compile:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"fsu::Stack<char, 10ul>::Pop()", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"fsu::Stack<char, 10ul>::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>      >&)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"fsu::Stack<char, 10ul>::Push(char const&)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"fsu::Stack<char, 10ul>::Stack(char)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"fsu::Stack<char, 10ul>::~Stack()", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"fsu::Stack<char, 10ul>::Display(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>  >&, char) const", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

My test client is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stack.h"

int main()
{
  typedef char ElementType;
  ElementType fill = '*';
  const size_t maxSize = 10;
  typedef fsu::Stack < ElementType , maxSize > StackType;
  StackType s(fill);

  s.Push('a');
  s.Push('b');
  s.Pop();

  s.Display(std::cout, '\0');
  s.Dump(std::cout);

  return 0;
} // end main
```

My header file:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace fsu
{
  template < typename T, size_t N = 100>
  class Stack
  {
  public:
    // Stack < T , N > API
    void     Push     (const T& t); // push t onto stack; error if full
    T        Pop      ();           // pop stack and return removed element; error
                                    //if stack is empty
    T&       Top      ();           // return top element of stack; error if empty
    const T& Top      () const;     // const version
    size_t   Size     () const;     // return number of elements in stack
    size_t   Capacity () const;     // return storage capacity [maximum size] of
                                    // stack
    bool     Empty    () const;     // return 1/true if stack is empty, 0/false if
                                    //not empty
    void     Clear    ();           // make the stack empty
    void     Display  (std::ostream& os, char ofc = '\0') const; // output stack
                                    // contents through os, top to bottom
    void     Dump     (std::ostream& os); // output all private data (for dev only)
    Stack             ();           // default constructor
    Stack             (T fill);     // puts "fill" in each slot of the underlying
                                    // array (keeps size = 0)
    Stack             (const Stack&); // copy constructor
    ~Stack            ();             // destructor
    Stack& operator = (const Stack&); // assignment operator

  private:
    const size_t capacity_;  // = N = size of array   - fixed during life of stack
    T            data_[N];   // array of T objects    - where T objects are stored
    size_t       size_;      // current size of stack - dynamic during life of stack
  };
}
```

And I will include only my implementation for the constructors and destructor here for the sake of brevity:

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <iostream>

// Stack < T , N > API

template < typename T , size_t N >
fsu::Stack<T,N>::Stack () : capacity_(N), data_(), size_(0)
{}

template < typename T , size_t N >
fsu::Stack<T,N>::Stack (T fill) : capacity_(N), size_(0)       // puts "fill" in each slot       of the underlying array (keeps size = 0)
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i < capacity_; ++i)
    data_[i] = fill;
}

template < typename T , size_t N >
fsu::Stack<T,N>::~Stack ()              // empty destructor
{
  //nothing here
}
```

I realize a good portion of my code still requires work, but it is this error that is preventing me from testing my code at all. I am lost as to what is causing this error and have spent considerable time on it. The issue seems to be affecting any method I call from my implementation. Any ideas as to what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to *explicitly instantiate* your templated class.  You can do that by adding the following line to the file with your implementation:

```
    template class fsu::Stack<char, 10>;
```

That will force the compiler to instantiate that version of the template class.

More on the syntax here:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template
(Scroll down to *Explicit Instantiation.*)

Comment: Just tried this and I'm still encountering the same errors unfortunately.

Comment: @RandomPleb: Do you have implementations of Dump, Push, Pop and Display?  Also, I'm not certain it matters, but historically I've put my explicit instantiations after the full implementation (ie. toward the bottom of the file).  Not sure if that's actually necessary though.

Comment: That works! I feel like we aren't supposed to do it this way, but at least I can test my code now. I still wonder what I'm doing wrong...

(And yes, I do have those implementations.)

Comment: When the implementation is separate from the interface, the compiler doesn't know what implementations to instantiate when it compiles the implementation.  Different compilers handle cross-compilation-unit instantiation differently.  From what I've seen with G++ & Linux, it seems to need the explicit instantiation model, so it compiles everything it needs at compile time.  With at least one embedded compiler that I use, it packages up an "intermediate code" version of the template and instantiates it at link time, which can lead to weird _compile_ errors at _link_ time.  Welcome to C++!